# Save information in the metadata itext7.2.2

Tags: itext7

I am working on the migration from version **5.5.8 to version 7.2.2 of Itext** but I have problems when I want to *save information in the metadata* since once the document has been signed it no longer allows me to save information in the document at the metadata level, a functionality that in version 5 was possible for me, in this new version it invalidates the signature, could you guide me on how I can achieve this functionality.

I am working on **java 8**.

It is possible to save information in the metadata of the document without any inconvenience but these must be entered before being signed and the information that I need to store there I cannot obtain it at another time if not until the document is being signed and it may contain the information of the n signatories, for this reason I cannot work with documents that have the signature invalidated.

```
InputStream pdfStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfOriginal);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteNewPdf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument pdfDoc =new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfStream), new PdfWriter(baos)); 
String metadatoInsert = "Hola soy una cadena de prueba";
if (!metadatoInsert.isEmpty()) {
pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo().setMoreInfo(propertiesData.getPrefixSignatureBox() + 
String.valueOf(signerNumber), metadatoInsert); 
pdfDoc.close();
pdfStream2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
}
PdfDocument pdfDocWrite = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfStream2), new PdfWriter(byteNewPdf));
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, byteNewPdf.toByteArray(), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
signer.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.NOT_CERTIFIED);
IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
IExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
signer.signDetached(digest, signature, chain, null, null,  null, 0 , subfilter);
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly assuming that `pdfOriginal` is already signed? In that case you forgot to open `pdfDoc` in append mode. Otherwise please explain in more detail.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment.

It is correct. pdfOriginal is a document that already has a signature or none and it is the document to which I must add a value to the metadata. Could you please tell me how I should open the document in add mode?

Thank you very much in advance, I'm still on the lookout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in a comment, the PDF `pdfOriginal` may already have a signature.

To not invalidate such a signature, you have to process that PDF in append mode.

You process that PDF in append mode by instantiating the `PdfDocument` for processing with `new StampingProperties().useAppendMode()`.

So in your code replace

```java
PdfDocument pdfDoc =new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfStream), new PdfWriter(baos));
```

by

```java
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfStream), new PdfWriter(baos),
    new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
```

Comment: I appreciate the help provided, I have carried out a test and it has worked for me.

I will continue to test to check different possible scenarios.